# 500 Internal error while saving data into Firestore

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a following process to load documents into Firestore:

1. Upload document(Its a JSON file) into GCS bucket,
2. Trigger Cloud Function when document get uploaded into bucket and save uploaded document into Firestore

I am using below code for saving data into firestore

```
#Save document in firestore
collection = db.collection(u'my_collection')
try:
    collection.document(u'' + file_name + '').set(data)
    print('Data saved successfully with document id {}'.format(file_name))
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception occurred while saving data into firestore.', e)
```

Problem arise when I uploaded large number of files (1000-2000) into the bucket simultaneously. Few of documents saved successfully but for few of them got below error.
Exception occurred while saving data into firestore. **500 An internal error occurred.**

**Edit 1**: Above error occurs when calling **set()** method

What is the way to diagnose why this occurred? If there is quota or limit issue or anything else?

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to be more specific about what exactly is generating that error and how you are observing it.  Are you saying that the call to `set()` failed with that error message?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks Doug for pointing it out. I edited the question and your assumption is correct, call to set() failed with that error message.

Comment: Is the issue still happening or it has been fixed?

Comment: This is still happening. For now I limited max instance size of the cloud function to 500. so max concurrent write would not exceed 500 and that seems working.